# Resolve relative pack URI in .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uri, .net-4.5

I want to compare two URI's that point to pages in my application. Unfortunately, JournalEntry pages from a Frame or Navigation window have a relative URI, but it does not match the URI syntax I use in my application. "/MyPage.xaml" is what I specify, and "MyDemo;component/MyPage.xaml" is what the JournalEntry shows. In both the IsAbsoluteUri property is false.

Is there an easy way for me to convert these relative URI's to absolute so I can use PackUriHelper.ComparePackUri to compare them? If I try to compare them as relative URI's the second one fails as not being relative. Uri.GetComponents fails because they aren't absolute.